# Android just wont load image exactly as it is

Tags: java, android, view, draw, android-bitmap

For example if I have a png which is 200x200 then I run

```
    mBackground=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);
```

the result is 400x400.
ofcourse I can do this;

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled=false;
    mBackground=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle,options);
```

now it is 200x200 but then when I draw

```
@Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground,0,0,mImagePaint); //density 160
    mImagePaint.setXfermode(mSourceOnTopMode);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mForground,0,0, mImagePaint); //density 320
    mImagePaint.setXfermode(null);
  }
```

It goes back to 400x400!!

It turns out its the density porperty playing the trick.A bitmap is a bitmap why introduce density?It is really disirable behavier, am I the only one get really annoyed by this?

Comment: Dont use decodeResource(). Instread open an InputStream for the resource and then use decodeStream().

Comment: Remove source image to folder drawable-nodpi